# C - How to initialize new array inside functions parameter when calling it

Tags: arrays, c, function, methods

```
void someVoid(int val[]){
    //doing something with val...
}

int main(){
    someVoid(???);
}
```

I am not sure how to call function, without declaring variable first, outside function parameters, in c

In c# this would be like this

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    someVoid(new int[]{...});
}
```

This would be convenient when calling function where you would need to insert dimensions or coordinates

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might try to use a compound literal: `someVoid(((int[]){1,2,3})`

Comment: A lone array parameter is typically wrong in C. You need to pass the size in too, because a `int arr[]` parameter actually means `int *arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* (maybe) do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void
print_ints(int *x, size_t s)
{
    while( s-- ){
        printf("%d\n", *x++);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int explicit[] = {1, 2, 3};
    print_ints((int[]){1, 2, 3}, 3);
    print_ints(explicit, sizeof explicit / sizeof *explicit);
    return 0;
}
```

but I would argue that you shouldn't.  In the above example, it takes one extra line of code to explicitly declare and initialize the variable.  At most, any function you call will "save" one line of code per variable used.  However, note the fragility of the hard-coded '3' in the first call.  You can avoid that particular issue by using a sentinel in the array, but that's certainly not always desirable.  Having the explicit variable is (IMO) more readable.  In addition, this is a newish language (mis)feature that will cause some confusion to a certain class of reader, and will generate compiler errors on some toolchains.  YMMV